# Regex for validating numbers preceding with two dashes (hyphens)

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I got stuck with regexp to validate only numbers from 1-10 that could have two dashes(hyphens) before, for example:

```
--9
```

or

```
--10
```

or

```
--1
```

but not

```
--11 or not --0
```

I tried like seems to me everything, example:

```
/(-\-\[1-10])/
```

What is wrong?

#### EDIT 1:

Thanks a lot for so many working examples!!

What if I also wanted to validate to numbers before all of this, example:

```
8--10 but not 0--10 or not 11--11
```

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
/--([1-9]|10:[1-9]|10)\b/
```

#### EDIT 2:

Oh, this one works, finally:

```
/^(10|[1-9])--(10|[1-9])$/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a try with:

```
/\b(?:[1-9]|10)--(?:[1-9]|10)\b/
```

Change according to OP's edit.

**Explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:\b(?:[1-9]|10)--(?:[1-9]|10)\b)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [1-9]                    any character of: '1' to '9'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    10                       '10'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  --                       '--'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [1-9]                    any character of: '1' to '9'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    10                       '10'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This would match `---10` as well.

Comment: Thank you everybody but I can only accept one answer unfortunately and M42 provided fastest second edit!

Comment: That would be great for the future readers (including myself) if you provided detailed explanation but if you're not I probably will when have more time! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I guess this will fit

```
/\-\-([1-9]|10)\b/
```

if you don't want to capture your number, add `?:` :

```
/\-\-(?:[1-9]|10)\b/
```

Comment: No need to escape hyphens `-`.

Comment: You're right. I'm doing that just because habit (with escape it will works well either in group or inline, so it's universal way to use it)

Answer (score 2):

The correct regex is

```
/\b--([1-9]|10)\b/
```

You're incorrectly escaping the first `[` of your character class as `\[`. The character class used is incorrect as well. It would be treated as a character class with members `1` to `1` and a `0` i.e. `[10]` which means it matches either `0` or `1`.

Also, the hyphens `-` don't need to be escaped outside a character class `[]`. To validate the numbers that come before the hyphens as well use

```
/\b([1-9]|10)--([1-9]|10)\b/
```

Answer (score 2):

Outside a character class, you don't need to escape hyphens. Also, your character class `[1-10]` will only match `1` and `0`, because `[1-10]` is equal to `[10]` and that will only match `1` and `0`. Try this regex:

```
/^--(10|[1-9])$/
```

Comment: This would match `---10` as well.

Comment: @Ravi: I added a caret sign. Now it won't longer match `---10`

Answer (score 1):

When you write `[1-10]`, it mean characters 1 to 1 + the 0 character. It as if you had write [0-1].

In fact, in your case, it would be better to test cases --1 to --9 and case --10 separately with something like : `/^(--10)|(--[1-9])$/`

You can test your regex on http://myregexp.com/